# how can i changes to the css in order to make tiles bigger

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, 2016

I have got this  css code for the the sharepoint tiles. how can i adjust this css in order to make make tiles bigger.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.ms-promlink-body {
 height: 100px;
}

div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
height: 110px !important;
  width: 110px !important;
  }

   div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-
   tileview-
  tile-content > a > div > span {
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  }

 div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img {
 max-width: 100%;
 width: 100% !important;
 }

 ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
 height: 100px;
padding: 0;
}

li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 16px;
 }

  div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded, div.ms-tileview-tile-
  titleTextLargeCollapsed, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeExpanded {
 padding: 3px;
}

    div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #002E4F;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 16px;
min-height: 36px;
min-width: 97px;
padding-left: 3px;
position: absolute;
top: -36px;
 }

 li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 14px;
 padding: 3px;
 }

.ms-promlink-header{
display:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Tiles to 125X125：

```
div.ms-promlink-body {
    height: 125px;
}

/*  tile dimensions, including inter-tile margin */
div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
    width: 134px !important;
    height: 134px !important;
}

/*  tile and title( + description) overlay dimensions */
div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    width: 125px !important;
    height: 125px !important;
}

/*  renders detailsBox effectively invisible at rest, and ensures that it returns to invisible after a short delay on mouseout  */
div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0s linear 0.3s;
}

/*  restores the detailsBox overlay color on mousein    */
div.ms-tileview-tile-content:hover > a > div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: background-color 0s linear 0s;
}

/*  tile background image dimensions */
div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

/*  title and description text  */
ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
    height: 125px;
    padding: 5px 8px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

/*  description text class  */
li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
    padding-top: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/*  title text when description not shown   */
div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 109px;
    height: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 8px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
}
```